# Xcode 9.4 Invalid/Untrusted Certificate Error

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, keychain

I've been working on an app and I've been able to build/run fine on simulators on real devices. I just tried Archiving and Verifying the product for the first time, and Verify had a code signing error. After seeing that error, I can no longer build the project. I get this error:

[image: Error 1]

So, I took a look at my keychain and I see this:

[image: Error 2]

What might cause my certificate to not be trusted, and how can I fix these errors?

Comment: you are Archiving in which mode debug or release ?

Comment: I believe debug because the app is unreleased but I never explicitly chose a mode

Comment: by default it will be in release mode only just check and change it to debug mode and try Archiving.

Comment: I'll try that later but right now I'm not able to archive at all because of the signing certificate error in Xcode.

Comment: try cleaning the project and rebuild don't archive it.

Comment: I tried that, it still gives the same errors.

Comment: plz get the new certificates and install in your machine.

Comment: I deleted the old certificates and used Xcode to generate new ones, and I still get the same error.

Comment: show your project build settings

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206143/ios-untrusted-developer-error-when-testing-app

Comment: I got really desperate so I re-installed Mac OS and that fixed my issue. Not sure why but might be worth a try if anyone else is having the same problem and feeling desperate.

Answer (score 0):

1- open keychain

2- select Certificates from bottom left

3- you should find your certificate

4- right click on it, then GetInfo
[image]

5- check if certificate not trusted